# Multiple Properties in 1 variable in scss

Tags: variables, sass

I am building a project in which i am using links in multiple places. i am giving them same color and same hover properties but i am using scss and i am nesting. I know i can style the link individually without nesting and it will apply to all links but i want to know that is their a way to create a variable that will allow me to apply multiple properties so that i do not repeat the code while nesting?
for ex- text-decoraton and color in 1 variable.

i tried to create a variable but as i added multiple properties VS code gave a semi-colon error... So i want to know that does a variable support multiple properties or not. if so then how to do it?

Comment: You can check what `placeholders` and `mixins` are in scss.